# Trying to understand Twilio

Tags: twilio

I recently signed up here as part of my course with some coaches. But, not many details given. wondering what is twilio and why we need and what all we can using twilio.
Really appreciate if someone can help me here to understand this product. Or at least route me to some place where i can learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio provides APIs and tools for customer engagement and communication. For example, if you're building an app in, say, JavaScript or Python, and you want your app to send and receive text messages, make and receive phone calls, video calls, have in-app or in-browser chat, two-factor authentication, email, and more, you use Twilio so you can implement those features quickly.

There's other products for debugging, hosting serverless applications, building chatbots, and more--you can see [all products offered here on the website](https://www.twilio.com/products).

There's also some code snippets and more details under [documentation here](https://www.twilio.com/docs).